# Using dplyr and stringr to replace all values starts with

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

my df

```
> df <- data.frame(food = c("fruit banana", "fruit apple", "fruit grape", "bread", "meat"), sold = rnorm(5, 100))
>   df
          food      sold
1 fruit banana  99.47171
2  fruit apple  99.40878
3  fruit grape  99.28727
4        bread  99.15934
5         meat 100.53438
```

Now I want to replace all values in food that starts with "fruit" and then group by food and summarise sold with sum sold.

```
> df %>%
+     mutate(food = replace(food, str_detect(food, "fruit"), "fruit")) %>% 
+     group_by(food) %>% 
+     summarise(sold = sum(sold))
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

    food      sold
  (fctr)     (dbl)
1  bread  99.15934
2   meat 100.53438
3     NA 298.16776
```

Why is this command not working? It gives me NA instead of fruit?

Comment: Well, `food` is of factor type, convert it into character and then run your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is working for me, I think your data is in factors:

Using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` while making the data as below or you can run `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` in the R environment to avoid the same:

```
df <- data.frame(food = c("fruit banana", "fruit apple", "fruit grape", "bread", "meat"), sold = rnorm(5, 100),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>%
mutate(food = replace(food, str_detect(food, "fruit"), "fruit")) %>% 
group_by(food) %>% 
summarise(sold = sum(sold))
```

**Output:**

```
 # A tibble: 3 × 2
       food      sold
      <chr>     <dbl>
    1 bread  99.67661
    2 fruit 300.28520
    3  meat  99.88566
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do this using `base R` without converting to `character` class by assigning the `levels` with 'fruit' to 'fruit' and use `aggregate` to get the `sum`

```
levels(df$food)[grepl("fruit", levels(df$food))] <- "fruit"
aggregate(sold~food, df, sum)
#   food      sold
#1 bread  99.41637
#2 fruit 300.41033
#3  meat 100.84746
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(food = c("fruit banana", "fruit apple", "fruit grape", 
                 "bread", "meat"), sold = rnorm(5, 100))
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the Q is tagged with `dplyr` and `stringr` I would like to propose an alternative solution using `data.table` because `data.table` deals with factors in a convenient and straightforward way:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[food %like% "^fruit", food := "fruit"][, .(sold = sum(sold)), by = food]
#    food      sold
#1: fruit 300.41033
#2: bread  99.41637
#3:  meat 100.84746
```

#### Data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(food = c("fruit banana", "fruit apple", "fruit grape", "bread", "meat"), 
                 sold = rnorm(5, 100))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two alternative solutions which use `forcats`, `stringr`, and regular expressions to directly manipulate factor levels.

If I understand correctly, the issue was caused by `food` being a factor which is not handled appropriately by `replace()`.

#### 1. `fct_collapse()`

The `fct_collapse()` function is used to collapse all factor levels which start with `"fruit "` (note the trailing blank) into factor level "fruit":

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(forcats)
df %>%
  group_by(food = fct_collapse(food, fruit = levels(food) %>% str_subset("^fruit "))) %>% 
  summarise(sold = sum(sold))
```

> ```
>   food         sold
>   <fct>       <dbl>
> 1 bread        99.4
> 2 egg fruits  100. 
> 3 fruit       300. 
> 4 fruity wine 100. 
> 5 meat        101.
> ```

Note that an enhanced sample data set is used which includes edge cases to better test the regular expression. Furthermore, the grouping variable is computed directly in `group_by()` which saves to call `mutate()` beforehand.

#### 2. `str_replace()` with *look-behind*

There is an even shorter solution which uses `str_replace()` instead of `replace()` together with a more sophisticated regular expression. The regular exprresion uses a *look-behind* in order to delete all characters after the leading `"fruit"` (including the blank which follows "fruit"):

```
df %>%
  group_by(food = str_replace(food, "(?<=^fruit)( .*)", "")) %>% 
  summarise(sold = sum(sold))
```

The result is the same as above.

#### Enhanced data sample set

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(food = c("fruit banana", "fruit apple", "fruit grape", "bread", 
                          "meat", "egg fruits", "fruity wine"), 
                 sold = rnorm(7, 100))
df
```

> ```
>           food      sold
> 1 fruit banana  99.45412
> 2  fruit apple 100.53659
> 3  fruit grape 100.41962
> 4        bread  99.41637
> 5         meat 100.84746
> 6   egg fruits 100.26602
> 7  fruity wine 100.44459
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`replace` does not work as intended, because column `food` is a factor variable and `fruit` is an unknown level.

One possible solution is to define the dataframe column `food` with the correct factor levels

```
df <- data.frame(food = 
  factor(c("fruit banana", "fruit apple", "fruit grape", "bread", "meat"), 
    levels =c("fruit banana", "fruit apple", "fruit grape", "bread", "meat", "fruit") ), 
    sold = rnorm(5, 100))
```

Easier would of course be to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

```
df <- data.frame(food = c("fruit banana", "fruit apple", "fruit grape", "bread", "meat"),
             sold = rnorm(5, 100), 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```